# Public University - How to get competent help?

Tags: graduate-school

I recently went back to school at a local public University. I'm not sure how to approach getting help (from any department, admissions, registrar etc.).  I understand they're state employees (I've dealt with the DMV more then enough in my lifetime).

Basically if I email it's rarely returned, if it actually is the short message wasn't fully read - and I get fragmented sentence answer (and this is from the head of the department).  I know they're understaffed and being anything but nice as possible will get me no where....

How do I approach this so I can get answers from staff without losing my cool?

Comment: "*I understand they're state employees (I've dealt with the DMV more then enough in my lifetime).* ... *How do I approach this so I can get answers from staff without losing my cool?*" - Start by thinking of them as people, rather than "state employees" which sounds like you are going in with some presupposed low expectations (that's an appropriate approach for all state employees, by the way). Also know that many of the things they can help you with are probably already provided on the university's website. Try as best you can to help yourself before asking others to help.

Comment: Any student who thinks they're going to get me to prioritize highly their problem just because I am a state employee (and refer to me as such) would be deprioritized to a level that is unbounded below.

Comment: You said elsewhere here that you were surprised by the responses you got so far. There is a lot implied in your question that you may not have intended to imply. First, you asked how to get "competent" help - this implies the help you are getting is *incompetent*, rather than focusing on your own communication strategies. Second, you bring up the DMV, often used as a comedic target for government inefficiency, which again implies you think someone at the university is at fault. Third, you say "without losing my cool" which, along with the rest of the context, suggests an anger problem.

Comment: You also mentioned there that "*I’m calling about a letter I got 2 weeks ago saying I’d be unenrolled unless a payment is sent - 5 days left now. I shows my payment is complete and FASFA confirmed the same.*" - This is not an issue to address with the head of any department, rather this sounds like an issue for the Burser's office or a similar department that is involved with the collection of tuition payments.

Comment: E-mailing the head of a university department as a student is like e-mailing the CEO or vice president of a company as a customer.  They simply don't have time to interact with each individual customer who needs assistance.  You'll be more likely to get useful help contacting the company's customer service department.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)).  By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Answer (score 11):

Make a phone call or meet them in person. That's usually the most appropriate way to get a reply from secretary staff. Very busy employee would disregard email response as not the top priority.

Comment: In my experience, meeting in person works great. This might be difficult for the head of the department and professors; you'll need to schedule a meeting. But for department administrators, financial aid officers, the registrar, etc. going in person is easy and usually wait time is minimal (unlike the DMV).

Answer (score 7):

I'm very sympathetic to your complaint! Indeed, I'm a professor and I am sometimes frustrated by my own university's bureaucracy.

In general, I recommend using the internet (and Google) to try to figure out answers to your own questions. You might need to ask for help anyway, but instead of

> "I need to sign up for Course X, but it's full. What do I do?"

you'll be able to ask

> "I tried to sign up for Course X, but it's full. The department website says I should sign up for the waiting list. I didn't understand where I should sign up though, could you please point that out to me?"

As a related issue, try to figure out the correct person to whom to address your question. Sometimes, students will show up to department offices and simply ask their question of the first person they see. (As an undergraduate, I was often guilty of this.) They might be in the middle of something, in a hurry, and/or not have job responsibilities which include knowing the answer to your question.

If you send e-mail to someone who doesn't have responsibility for addressing your particular question (e.g., you ask the department chair how to pay your tuition), it may be ignored as spam. Good manners dictate that they should at least say "Sorry, I don't know", and direct you to the correct person to contact (if they know) -- but they might not.

So, in short, try to figure out who is responsible for what, and take first steps towards answering your own questions. And, finally, remember that sometimes you'll do all the right things, and still not be treated politely. That happens. Good luck!

Comment: I understand what you're saying but these are related to having my transcripts reviewed (sent in May), do I need to take X class as decided by dept. chair as this all hinges on my audit.  Also getting my tuition paid would be a plus.

Comment: @WentzWagon: I'm afraid that don't understand what you mean, or are trying to do. No need to clarify here -- I won't be able to solve your problem anyway -- but allow me to add to my advice: write your e-mailed requests so that the recipient can tell exactly what you are trying to do, why and at whose request, and what you are asking them for.

Comment: @WentzWagon It's pretty hard to understand what you are trying to say: in your question, your comments, and your non-answer answer. Some of this might be because you are being purposefully vague here, which is fine - that's actually appropriate, if your question is too specific it will be closed. However, I would rethink your form of communication to this department head, you might not be making much sense to them either, and you might *think* they are the right person to deal with but they aren't, all of which makes you difficult to help.